# Rails spilt hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

How, if it's possible, can I split this hash:

```
{2011=>["46", "47", "48", "49"]}
```

Into

```
46
47
48
49
```

So I get four separate records to work with.
Thanks...

Comment: It's not completely clear what you want. Can you give a bit more detail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate over it with each.

```
years = {2011=>["46", "47", "48", "49"]}

years.each do |year, values|
  values.each do |value|
    puts value
  end
end

#=> 46
#=> 47
#=> 48
#=> 49
```

Comment: I don't think that's doing what you think it's doing. Try `years.each {|yr, val| puts val.inspect}` to see what I mean. You may also find `puts [1,2,3]` instructive.

Answer (score 0):

```
my_hash = {2011=>["46", "47", "48", "49"]}
element1, element2, element3, element4 = my_hash[2011]
```

so

```
element1
#=> "46"
element4
#=> "49"
# ETC
```

Answer (score 0):

This?

```
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :005 > years = {2011=>["46", "47", "48", "49"]}
```

=> {2011=>["46", "47", "48", "49"]}

```
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :006 > years.values.flatten
```

=> ["46", "47", "48", "49"]

Flatten simply makes one-dimensional array in case you have multiple years.

http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Hash.html